# Why is article state undefined after api call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When i follow the endpoints through from the home page then article state gets set on component did mount. I can see this in the console log but I am unable to use that data when rendering on the page.

I have created a loading component that gets rendered before the fetch function is returned.

The state is also gone on a page refresh so that could be part of the problem but I cant seem to be able fix it.

```
class Article extends Component {

state = {
    toggleComments: false,
    article: '',
    isLoading: true
}
render() {

    const { isLoading } = this.state;
    if (isLoading) return <Loading />;

    return <div>
        <p>artilce</p>
        {console.log(this.state.article.article, 'article here')}
        <button type="submit">
          <Link to="/articles">Back</Link>
        </button>
        <button onClick={this.handleToggleComments} type="submit">
          comments
        </button>
        {this.state.toggleComments && <Comments />}
      </div>;
}
componentDidMount = () => {
    this.handleFetchArticle();

}

handleToggleComments = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
        toggleComments: !prevState.toggleComments
    }))
}
handleFetchArticle = () => {
    api.fetchArticle(this.props.articleId)
    .then(article => {
        this.setState({
            article,
            isLoading: false
        })
    })
}
}
```

I need to be able to access the data at the point of the console log.

Comment: you should log and check what is the value of `article` inside `then`

Comment: at that point im getting the article back

Comment: What is your full state from inside the render method?

Comment: if I come from the previous endpoint onto the page then it is article: {articicle data}
isLoading: false
toggleComments: false, but if I refresh the page then article is undefined